# how can we embedded locally created html5 web application into android 

Tags: android

I created one login form with html5 application.

Then how can i add this same application into andriod .

doubt: How can i configure this application into our local application server like apache tomcat and  how can i use it in andriod.

please help me on this .

Answer (score 2):

WebView is the embeddable browser component in Android view system. 
You can create a native application in Android and in the layout, you can include a webview object.

For the webview you can put your html5 web app as part of the loadurl method if your web page is hosted on a server. If it is locally with you, you can put it in raw folder and can load the page from there.

Read the [WebView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) and get started with it.